# How do I create a json array using POST?

Tags: php, json, forms

Please forget my bad English.

I created a simple application using the GD library, but on form must inform the text from the image, the padding x and y padding, that will be received in DG variables in PHP: $ title, $ x and $ y.

In file form.php I have a simple form:

```
  <form method = "POST">
   Title <input type = "text">
    X <input type = "text">
    Y <input type = "text">
   / * Others fields * /
</ form>
```

I do not know how to create a json with the data from the form, and then I continue in php:

```
$ json = json_decode ($ jsondata, true);
```

Comment: `json_encode($_POST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is tiny code snipped that allows you to do that:

```
<form method = "POST">
    Title <input name="title" type = "text">
    X <input name="x" type = "text">
    Y <input name="y" type = "text">
    <!-- other fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $json = json_encode($_POST);

    echo $json;
}
?>
```